# Getting URL of YouTube video with `youtube-dl` is slow, without downloading video

Tags: networking, performance, downloads, download-speed, youtube-dl

I want to get the URL using youtube-dl, and the "simulate" option `-g` that does not download the video.

So I gave the following command:

```
youtube-dl -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4JGSAmu4lg
```

It gave the following output after 7 to 8 seconds

```
https://r20---sn-cvh7zn7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?initcwndbps=1113000&mt=1408702970&requiressl=yes&ipbits=0&sver=3&fexp=901454%2C902408%2C919145%2C924626%2C927622%2C927904%2C931330%2C931983%2C934024%2C934030%2C934804%2C945118%2C945308%2C946023%2C951914&ratebypass=yes&signature=38F111D46D72FFC50B47D50B3C9A631099BF5F83.FA134C91F407989B95ACADC1F1F6946B8F18C158&upn=tU0u5t7A2Uw&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mm=31&expire=1408724634&id=o-AJNPuDp9TKMKiwzUwvSk76W7JdA0cx0bRSum9mPJJ7Vo&mv=u&source=youtube&ms=au&key=yt5&ip=115.113.1.50&itag=18
```

But the problem is it is taking around 7 to 8 seconds for querying the URL.
Is there any way so that it can be faster?

Comment: What do you mean with "simulate", exactly?

Comment: when we give the option -g followed by youtube-dl, it will generate(simulate) URL as I mentioned the as output.

Answer (score 10):

### The time is spend doing work

The command does not hang or wait for something wasting time,
it actually does work that takes time; It most probably takes time by adding up multiple small network delays. But it could also be that there are delays on the youtube side, that add up.

That it just the time it takes to download the HTML that is needed;
The command needs to make at least two HTTP requests, one after another, and probably more.

So if anything is slow, it's multiplied by the number of requests already.

For me it takes 1.5 seconds on a very fast line - that is not that far from 8 seconds.

### How to find out

I'll show the commands I used to find out:

To make the examples more tidy, we use a variable for the URL:

```
$ u="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4JGSAmu4lg"
```

We want to measure the duration of commands; Using the command `time` needs to take care not to mix up the command and the shell builtin. We use a small function to make the lines shorter:

```
$ t(){/usr/bin/time -f 'Time: %es' "$@";}
```

Your command writes out the URL of the video file (truncated to 80 columns):

```
$ youtube-dl -g "$u"
https://r20---sn-cxg7en7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=091F68E823
```

Let's measure the time it takes to run on my computer:

```
$ t youtube-dl -g "$u"
https://r20---sn-cxg7en7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=091F68E823
Time: 1.44s
```

Ok, one and a half seconds. Faster than in the question, but not that much faster.
But how is it spending the time? Maybe it does download the video in some hidden way and discards it? The video is 11min in 360p. Just downloading it with no options takes about 13s - ten times longer.
Need to take a closer look, with the verbose option `-v`:

```
$ t youtube-dl -v -g "$u"
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['-v', '-g', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4J
[debug] Encodings: locale 'UTF-8', fs 'UTF-8', out 'UTF-8', pref: 'UTF-8'
[debug] youtube-dl version 2014.02.06
[debug] Python version 2.7.6 - Linux-3.13.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14
[debug] Proxy map: {}
https://r20---sn-cxg7en7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cinitcwn
Time: 1.40s
```

Oh, there is some delay before the '[debug]' lines are printed. Looks like `youtube-dl` spends some time for it's own configuration setup. It's a quarter of a second or so, not the delay we are looking for. But what we can learn from it is that the `youtube-dl` implementation itself may be slow.
After the messages, nothing happens until the result URL is printed. So we still do not see the interesting part.
The option `-g` is to "simulate" the video download in the sense that it does the complicated part of finding out that semi-secret URL, prints it, but then skips the actual download in the end. There is a similar option `-s` that does not output the URL, and seems similar otherwise. Let's assume it's similar enough if it takes about the same time; We need to check that.

```
$ t youtube-dl -v -s "$u"
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['-v', '-s', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4J
[debug] Encodings: locale 'UTF-8', fs 'UTF-8', out 'UTF-8', pref: 'UTF-8'
[debug] youtube-dl version 2014.02.06
[debug] Python version 2.7.6 - Linux-3.13.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] k4JGSAmu4lg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] k4JGSAmu4lg: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] k4JGSAmu4lg: Extracting video information
Time: 1.45s
```

Ok, `-s` takes the same time as `-g`, so it's ok to replace them for testing.
More interesting is that we got more output now. And it's printed with an interesting timing: The lines get printed with a similar delay to each other, so it seems they are about the actions that are actually taking the time we look for.
From the messages, at least two web pages are downloaded. But we can assume that the word "page" will not mean a single HTTP request and a single HTML document.

### What did we learn?

The main point is, the work of the program does actually take time, it's not waiting for something, or hanging.
Also, we see multiple steps taking similar amounts of time. There is not much to calculate, so that's network roundtrips in some way, adding up.
That means, the latency of our connection is important only here. The throughput of the connection is just irrelevant.

If you would make your internet connection faster so it can transfer data at double speed - that would not help at all.
But if you can get better `ping` times, that will make it much faster.
It's not about 'ping' times to your internet service provider, though; The ping time all the way to YouTube it what matters - and may be not possible to change.

Interestingly, for the next step, downloading a video, the requirements for a fast line are exactly the opposite: latency is not relevant at all, and throughput really matters.

### Not tired yet?

Want still more details to understand what the time is really spend on?
The next step would be to trace the HTTP connection; I would suspect that it may show many more roundtrips than two, for redirects for example. You could use `wireshark`, or a logging HTTP proxy, or `strace` to just count the system calls for connecting or writing.

For today, we have both looked deep enough into the rabbit hole of networking.

Comment: So, what could be the reason for such long time?
Is it due ti slow network connection?

Comment: Depends on how slow it is - what is the question?   Wait a minute for details of my examples, I'm writing them.

Comment: My question is : Is the delay is due to slow network connection?

Comment: Yes, partially. The question is less simple than it sounds ;) It's not about the throughput of the connection. The latency is important here. From what I can tell, there are at least three HTTP roundtrips - but maybe more. All delays are multiplied by this number, that adds up. I do not know anything about your connection; It could be slow on the YouTube end, hard to tell without measuring. Try some other things on the net for which you know how fast they are, and check whether it feels slower, or normal.

Comment: So, I added some details :)

Comment: When i tried to execute the following command 

$ t(){/usr/bin/time -f 'Time: %es' "$@";}

I got the error saying :

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{/usr/bin/time'

Comment: The internet connection maybe slow

Answer (score 6):

Just do a:

```
youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4JGSAmu4lg' | jq -r '.id' | sed 's_^_https://youtube.com/v/_'
```

<sub>[Source](http://zmwangx.github.io/blog/2014-11-05-list-youtube-playlist-with-youtube-dl.html)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There might be another reason. `youtube-dl` is distributed as a zipped Python application. Each time you run it, it extracts it and then runs it.

You can manually extract it with the `unzip` command. Then run `__main__.py` as you would run `youtube-dl`. On a low powered computer, like the Pi, that will noticeably boost your performance.

Comment: This is pretty unlikely, reading files from disk is usually very slow compared to a most things a computer can do. dumping a smaller compressed file into memory and then decompressing it back into memory can be faster than reading a larger file from disk.